# Trouble with printf in C

Tags: c, printf

I am confused by how this C program is running. I am just trying to use a structure to store some variables and then be able to print them out in a separate function. Below is my code. What I don't understand is why is my first output includes both ip and key and not just ip.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct device {
    char ip[6];
    char key[5];
};

void check(struct device cred);

int main ()
{
    int i;
    struct device cred[10];

    strcpy(cred[0].ip, "192.16");
    strcpy(cred[0].key, "45EA9");

    check(cred[0]);
    return 0;
}

void check(struct device cred)
{
    printf("IP: %s\n", cred.ip);
    printf("Key: %s\n", cred.key);
}

Output:

IP: 192.1645EA9
Key: 45EA9
```

Comment: Hint: IPv4 addresses are a lot longer than six characters. Don't forget the terminator character, either.

Comment: You are overflowing `ip`, it should be `char ip[7]` to hold the `'\0'`-terminating byte. Same for `key`.

Comment: How were you expecting `printf` to know where to stop?

Comment: A string is a character sequence *including a 0-valued terminator*; you need to set aside at least `N+1` elements to store an `N`-character string.  Since the terminator wasn't there, `printf` just kept going and printed the contents of `key`.

Comment: Note that if you reversed the order of the `strcpy()` operations, you'd probably get nothing printed for the `cred.key`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
strcpy(cred[0].ip, "192.16");
```

is undefined behavior. The target has not enough space for holding the `\0`. So it writes that out of the array bounds resulting in UB. Same problem is there with `key` also.

Printing it with `%s` format specifier will now also be undefined behavior for the very reason described above. `printf` tries to print the characters starting from the address pointed by the argument passed to it — but it doesn't find the `\0` within the array so it reads beyonds the array which is undefined behavior.

You have to make the array size big enough to hold the characters of the string literals including the nul terminating `char`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: *strings in C are one character longer than they appear*.
That's because the program has to know where the end of a string is – and this is marked with an *additional* zero byte (ASCII NUL code) appended.

So, your string `"192.16"` is actually a 7-byte array whose last byte is zero. When you `strcpy` it into `cred.ip` that seventh byte lands *outside* the array, which invokes an Undefined Behaviour.

In your case apparently the arrays `cred.ip`and `cred.key` touch one another, so that terminating NUL byte is stored as the first byte of `cred.key`. The next moment it gets *overwritten* by the first character of `"45EA9"`.

This way the first string looses its terminator, and the second one gets effectively *appended* to it – hence the output consisting of both strings glued.

Answer (score 0):

You where allocating less space than you actually needed. Always make sure to allocate +1 for the NULL Character '\0'.